# How to avoid instant transition of visibility

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, css-transitions

I've tried many methods to achieve the desired effect, for example deleting a class and then adding a new one, also tried to toggle a class, but nothing works for me. Maybe it can be done in a different way, but I do not know how. So the question is: How to make a transition from visible to hidden and vice versa smoother over a defined period of time?

```js
let trigger = document.querySelector("#reset");
let show = document.querySelector("#show");

trigger.addEventListener("click", function() {
  trigger.classList.replace("show", "hidden");
});

show.addEventListener("click", function() {
  trigger.classList.replace("hidden", "show");
});
```

```css
.grid {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 8px rgba(255, 213, 79, 0.50);
  font-size: 50px;
  border-radius: 5%;
  padding-top: 3%;
  padding-bottom: 3%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: #ffd54f;
  float: left;
  margin: 1.66%;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.grid:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 15px rgba(255, 213, 79, 0.50);
  background-color: #FFC107;
}

.grid:active {
  border-width: 3px;
  background-color: #FFA000;
}

.hidden {
  transition: all 0.5s;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.show {
  transition: all 0.5s;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div id="reset" class="grid show">Hide</div>
<button id="show">show again</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `hidden` and `visible` are not *numeric* or *calculable values*, therefore can't be *animated*, you will have to settle for `0` and `1` of the `opacity` *property*:

```js
let trigger = document.querySelector("#reset");
let show = document.querySelector("#show");

trigger.addEventListener("click", function() {
  trigger.classList.replace("show", "hidden");
});

show.addEventListener("click", function() {
  trigger.classList.replace("hidden", "show");
});
```

```css
.grid {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 8px rgba(255, 213, 79, 0.50);
  font-size: 50px;
  border-radius: 5%;
  padding-top: 3%;
  padding-bottom: 3%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: #ffd54f;
  float: left;
  margin: 1.66%;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.grid:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 15px rgba(255, 213, 79, 0.50);
  background-color: #FFC107;
}

.grid:active {
  border-width: 3px;
  background-color: #FFA000;
}

.hidden {
  transition: all 0.5s;
  /*visibility: hidden;*/
  opacity: 0;
}

.show {
  transition: all 0.5s;
  /*visibility: visible;*/
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="reset" class="grid show">Hide</div>
<button id="show">show again</button>
```